# Fixed menu, Not working on iphone?

Tags: android, html, ios, css, iphone

I have worked on a web page with a fixed menu on top of the page, in mobile version of android the menu works fine, fixed on top of the page, but on iPhone it doen't seem to work, someone knows why? Here is my menu div and container:

```css
    .container{padding-top: 160px;z-index: 0;}

    .menu{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 95%;
        margin-left: 2.5%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: auto;
        position: fixed;
        padding-bottom: 2%;
        z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: if you want to check the page is: www.diegocervantes.com/warlo

Comment: please check the link in mobile version if you have an iphone, to view the problem

Comment: Can you reproduce it in the iphone emulator in dev tools or is the problem only on iphone devices?

Comment: yes i have seen the page on iphone and in my android, in my moto it works fine, but the problems seems only to be on iphone devices

Answer (score 0):

Remove overflow: scroll, overflow: auto; and -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; from `.menu` in your css file. I've tested this using Safari on Mac as the problem appears there too until I removed these properties.